# Symfony generate links for twig rendered emails sent with cron tasks

Tags: email, symfony, dns, cron

I'm having some problems while generating paths in emails rendered with twig on Symfony

Here is what I'm doing

```
<a href="{{ domain_parameter ~ path('news_homepage') }}"> My Link </a>
```

And on parameters.yml

```
domain_parameter: http://mydomain.com
```

On the routing

```
news_homepage:
    pattern:  /news
    defaults: { _controller: newsBundle:News:index }
```

I then send emails with cron tasked

While doing so I'm expecting to get urls looking like this :

```
http://mydomain.com/news
```

But i'm getting this :

```
http://mydomain.com/website.com/web/app.php/news
```

If I use "url" instead of "path", it will result with :

```
http://localhost/var/www/website.com/web/app.php/news
```

Do you have any idea on how could I get this to work as expected? Thanks you in advance

Comment: Do you have something in your .htaccess file? What setting did you define for default path so that you get `website.com/...` when you use `path` command?

Comment: Javad, that's in my apache virtual host that I define the "Root" of mydomain.com to be binded to the folder /var/www/website.com/ where my Symfony's project is

Comment: That's true but if you define `website.com` as your virtual host then the `path` command should not show `website.com/web/app.php/something` it should just print `/Symfony/web/app.php/something`. make sure you have a correct configuration for default path in `config.yml`

Comment: Yes Javad but it works well in all the situations (it generates links as you expect  eg. "website.com/news") except with CRON usage

Comment: Though this sounds you have the issue in crontab. Could you provide what do you have in shell script or what do you call in your crontab?

Comment: You're right Javad, this is caused by the CRON : 0 */1 * * * curl -s localhost/mydomain.com/web/app.php/crontask/generate_mail >/dev/null But, it's necessary that I call it with localhost for security reasons

Comment: Instead of that I recommend to create a command through Symfony then use the command in a shell script, then run the shell in your cron. Actually I think it's not secure to use the url path as you mentioned because for that specific routing you need to set security as `anonymous : true` or something else.

Comment: You can find more info about how to create command in Symfony through this link [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html] Also this link is helpful due to mail sending through command [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html]

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have  web/app.php in your links, so you might want to change your htaccess

If you want to "just have the proper domain" there, you could try |replace like:

```
{{ path('news_homepage')|replace({'website.com': domain_parameter}) }}
```

in addition, path() should give you just /news so there seems to be something wrong with your configuration

Comment: Actually path works well when I generate links inside the application with a request context. The only situation where it does not work is when I use path with CRON (so there's no context request), the solution to use replace filter is correct thanks but I want to use it as a last chance, I hope there's something "cleaner" to use

Comment: You can also set the hostname inside the command you execute by:
Symfony documentation provides you with a solution here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

As if there is no proper request, you have to provide the context with a proper hostname manually, either by config or by setting it in the context object.
so you can just use: $this->container->get('router')->getContext()->setHost('myhostname');

Comment: Bartlomiej, it's still generates routes like http://mydomain.com/website.com/web/app.php/news while setting manually the context's host as you advised me

Comment: check if you dont have "website.com" in your config directory (in config.yml or parameters.yml or whichever of .yml files) or in htaccess file

Comment: Nope, I don't have nothing else than a rewriting that makes links http://mydomain.com to be rewrited to http://mydomain.com/web/app.php/[URL_PARAMS]

Answer (score 0):

Javad's solution is the better one.

I ended up with making commands classes instead of controllers called with HTTP requests.

To have a request context at each one of the commands, i specify this :

```
$requestCtx = $container->get('router')->getContext();
$requestCtx->setHost($container->getParameter('app_domain'));
$requestCtx->setBaseUrl('');
$requestCtx->setScheme('http');
```

I have also replaced all "path" functions (from twig templates that I use to generate emailsà) by "url" which can now generating expected links thanks to the specified context.